# Реализация скролла в области, по нажатию кнопки, в которой появляются QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qscrollarea

Работаю с QT-дизайнером, есть 2 кнопки **Q** и **A** па нажатию любой из них внутри фрейма появляются поля ввода. 
Если создать много таких полей то они уходят за пределы фрейма. 
Не могу реализовать скролл. Видел много реализаций с помощью `QScrollArea`, но все мои попытки были тщетны.

**Код дизайнера:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Q = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Q.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 221, 81))
        self.Q.setObjectName("Q")
        self.A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 40, 221, 81))
        self.A.setObjectName("A")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 160, 721, 381))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background: #ffffff")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Q.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Q"))
        self.A.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
```

**Код создания полей:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QGridLayout, QWidget, QScrollArea
from scroll import Ui_MainWindow

class StartWork(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartWork, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.buttonsArrQ = []
        self.buttonsArrA = []
        self.button_iter_nameQ = 0
        self.button_iter_nameA = 0
        self.btn_positionQ = 10
        self.btn_positionA = 20
        self.stairs = 20
        self.construct_panel = self.ui.frame

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(1129, 687)

        self.ui.Q.clicked.connect(self.cr1)
        self.ui.A.clicked.connect(self.cr2)


    def cr1(self):
        print('Q')
        self.buttonsArrQ.append(QLineEdit('{}'.format(self.button_iter_nameQ), self.construct_panel))
        self.buttonsArrQ[self.button_iter_nameQ].move(self.btn_positionQ, self.stairs)
        self.stairs += 35
        self.buttonsArrQ[self.button_iter_nameQ].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.buttonsArrQ[self.button_iter_nameQ].setStyleSheet(
            '''
            QLineEdit
            {
                background-color: rgb(211, 224, 206);
                border: 2px solid #9cb8a0;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 650;
                height: 30;
            }
            '''
        )
        self.buttonsArrQ[self.button_iter_nameQ].show()
        self.button_iter_nameQ += 1

    def cr2(self):
        print('A')
        self.buttonsArrA.append(QLineEdit('{}'.format(self.button_iter_nameA), self.construct_panel))
        self.buttonsArrA[self.button_iter_nameA].move(self.btn_positionA, self.stairs)
        self.stairs += 35
        self.buttonsArrA[self.button_iter_nameA].setStyleSheet(
            '''
            QLineEdit
            {
                background-color: rgb(211, 224, 206);
                border: 2px solid #9cb8a0;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 650;
                height: 30;
            }
            '''
        )
        self.buttonsArrA[self.button_iter_nameA].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.buttonsArrA[self.button_iter_nameA].show()
        self.button_iter_nameA += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = StartWork()
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного поправил ваш код и отметил как сделать скролл, попробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, \
    QGridLayout, QWidget, QScrollArea

#from scroll import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Q = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Q.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 221, 81))
        self.Q.setObjectName("Q")
        self.A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 40, 221, 81))
        self.A.setObjectName("A")
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 160, 721, 381))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
#        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background: #aa3a3a")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Q.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Q"))
        self.A.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))


class StartWork(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartWork, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.button_iter_nameQ = 0
        self.button_iter_nameA = 0

        self.init_UI()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 160, 721, 381))
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.ui.frame)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.frame)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(111, 1)                  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def init_UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(1129, 687)
        self.ui.Q.clicked.connect(self.cr1)
        self.ui.A.clicked.connect(self.cr2)

    def cr1(self):
        lineEdit = QLineEdit('{}'.format(self.button_iter_nameQ))
        self.layout.addWidget(lineEdit)                                        # +++
        self.button_iter_nameQ += 1

    def cr2(self):
        lineEdit = QLineEdit('{}'.format(self.button_iter_nameA))
        lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.layout.addWidget(lineEdit)                                        # +++
        self.button_iter_nameA += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QFrame {
            background: #aa3a3a;
        }
        QLineEdit {
            background-color: rgb(211, 224, 206);
            border: 2px solid #9cb8a0;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 650;
            height: 30;
        }
    ''')
    application = StartWork()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: СПАСИИИБОООО!))